# Water dripping from freezer into fridge top shelf

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge has recently started dripping water into the top shelf. Have you encountered this? Any tips on how to fix it will be appreciated. Can I do it myself or do I need a specialist? It's not under warranty.

Here is a short video of the water dripping.

https://youtu.be/IIJjDIw8Htc

https://youtu.be/0uGOpegH0Dc

[image]

[image]

Thanks for reading. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Turn off water to ice maker. 
If it still drips you have a blocked drain line. Drain line carries condensate from freezer coil to a pan in bottom of the fridge where heat from motor causes it to evaporate.

Exact directions for unblocking drain line will depend on your specific model fridge which you have not included in the question.

Generally  (2) unplug power.   (3) remove coil cover in back of freezer. There will be ice in the tray under the coil. Allow it to melt or speed up the process with a hair dryer.

Once you can see where the hole is that carries water to the bottom pan you will (4) clear the line with a blast of compressed air.

(5) Allow all ice build up in coil to melt using towels to soak up water,keeping too much from over filling bottom pan.

(6) Re install freezer coil cover and power back on.

Of course if your leak stops after step one there is a problem with ice maker supply line.